# Reading JSON object's properties in a loop

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following object:

```
var obj={
  "main": {
    "temp": 281.52,
    "feels_like": 278.99,
    "temp_min": 280.15,
    "temp_max": 283.71,
    "pressure": 1016,
    "humidity": 93
  }
}
```

I know we can access the properties like this:

```
obj.main.temp;
```

Now suppose the properties of `main` are dynamic. For that reason I need to loop though it to find the properties present in `main`.

I need a way to display the properties and their values.

What I've tried is:

```
 for(i=0;i<obj.main.length;i++){
     console.log(obj.main[i]);
     //should log temp
 }
```

Comment: _availble solutions are for row wise data reading..._ Loop over the rows and collect your column

Comment: show us your best attempt (code), please read [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved it using this

```
for (var key in obj) {
    //get all the properties one by one.  
    obj[key]
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var obj={
"main": {
    "temp": 281.52,
    "feels_like": 278.99,
    "temp_min": 280.15,
    "temp_max": 283.71,
    "pressure": 1016,
    "humidity": 93
  }
}

let allKeys = Object.keys(obj.main);
allKeys.forEach((key) => {
    console.log(`key: ${key}`)
    console.log(`value: ${(obj.main)[key]}`);
});

/*
Output:

key: temp
value: 281.52
key: feels_like
value: 278.99
key: temp_min
value: 280.15
key: temp_max
value: 283.71
key: pressure
value: 1016
key: humidity
value: 93
*/
```

Answer (score -1):

Objects don't have numeric properties or a `length` property. So a `for (i = 0; i < obj.main.length; i++) { obj.main[i] }` loop won't work because you're incrementing and accessing a numeric index/key `i`. That's for arrays.

You can traverse object properties using `for (key in obj.main) { obj.main[key] }`, that'll do what you want. There's one caveat though: this will also iterate through prototype properties (which is not a problem in this specific case). You can use [object.hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) to check that, but I think you have better options.

A more simple approach is to create an array from the object:

```js
let array = Object.keys(obj.main);
```

And iterate over that array:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  console.log(obj.main[array[i]]); // array[i] is the key
}
```

Or the more modern for-of loop:

```js
for (let key of array) {
  console.log(obj.main[key]);
}
```

Alternatively, you can use array methods like:

```js
array.forEach(function (key) {
  console.log(obj.main[key]);
});
```

Instead of creating an array of keys, you can create arrays with other shapes, too. Using [Object.keys(object)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) will return an array of keys, [Object.values(object)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) an array of values and [Object.entries(object)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) an array of key-value pairs.